# ORMLite Java, casing of sequences

Tags: java, postgresql, ormlite, quoted-identifier

I am trying to connect to postgresql with ORMlite from a **Java** client.
the DB gets generated perfectly, but when I try to insert something into a table that is using an autoincrement id I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "commandusage_id_seq" does not exist
```

When I check the DB I can see a "commandUsage_id_seq" sequence has been created. With a Capital U.

How can I configure ORMLite to use all the same casing for both creating and interacting with the DB ? I couldn't find this in the documentation

Thanks in advace.

update:

When explicitly setting the sequenceId I can circumvent the issue

```
generatedIdSequence = "commandusage_id_seq"
```

but still I would like to know if this is possible by setting some config for ORMLite instead of setting this per DBObject class

update2:

URL of the package to prevent confusion: [ORMLite](https://ormlite.com/)

update3:

Below a snippet of the code and how it works. Again I would like to know if ORMLite is capable of doing the to lowercase conversion automatically instead of me doing it explicitly.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "commandusage", daoClass = CommandUsageDaoImpl.class)
public class CommandUsage {
@DatabaseField(columnName = "id", generatedIdSequence = "commandusage_id_seq")
private transient int identifier;
```

Comment: Hi, that's for .NET and it seems like ORMLite for Java doesn't have a NamingStrategy option, or I have missed it in the documentation.

Comment: ah, my bad, https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#columnName-- does that help? You could define your own override for the column name how it is in the database.

Comment: Hi good suggestion,
But the sequences are not column names, so that option didn't work. if you check my original answer, the first update is a workaround that works.

Comment: well, technically it's a column name, but you allow orm lite to create the primary key column, and the way you defined the column name is the official supported way. There are some methods in the class reader that force upCase with english locale as default. You could try forking orm lite and just modify the database interpreting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I check the DB I can see a "commandUsage_id_seq" sequence has been created. With a Capital U.

Interesting.  After some initial confusion on my part, this seems like a bug a in ORMLite.  The pattern is if you force a table name with mixed case (typical is to downcase the name) and then ask for a sequence-id on it in Postgresql:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "TableNameCaseWithSeqeuence")
private static class TableNameCaseWithSeqeuence {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;
    ...
}
```

I've got a fix in trunk but it's going to take a bit to spin a release.
The workaround right now is to extend the `PostgresDatabaseType` and inject it into your `ConnectionSource`.  It should do something like:

```
public OurPostgresDatabaseType extends PostgresDatabaseType {
    // constructors ...
    @Override
    public String generateIdSequenceName(String tableName, FieldType idType) {
        String name = tableName + DEFAULT_SEQUENCE_SUFFIX;
        return downCaseString(name, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did that. using the generatedIdSequence I am able to both auto generate and ID and name the column.
Although that's not really what I want.

Comment: Like I said, it's not an issue of the name being wrong. it's an issue of the casing that's causing issues. PostgreSQL is expecting all lowercase and (without the workaround) ORMLite is using mixed casing.
I have added a snippet to my question

Comment: Ok.  This is a bug @Nick now that I understand the problem.   I've edited my answer to show a workaround and I hope to push out a new release soon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the workaround. I will try that out soon. Marked your answer as the solution